# how to compute joint pmf of (x,y)

Tags: regression, density-function

I want to know how to compute joint pmf of (x,y) where x follows exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and $y=x+\epsilon $, $\epsilon$ follows standard normal distribution. x and $\epsilon$ are independent.

and how to compute pdf of y.

> the question is to show $f(x|y)=\frac{\phi(x-(y-\lambda))}{\Phi(y-\lambda)}$, where $\phi,\Phi$ are pdf and cdf of standard normal. I guess this equation is originated from $f(x|y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}$, so I need to compute the joint pdf and the pdf of y. I tried but can't get the same form as shown above.

Comment: Could you explain what statistical problem this question might be connected with?

Comment: Where are you stuck? what have you tried so far? is this a self-study question?

Comment: @Xi'an I have update the question. : )

Comment: You are asking for two different things: the joint pdf, $f(x,y)$, and the *conditional* pdf $f(x|y)$. Because $x$ and $\epsilon$ are independent, the joint pdf is obtained with a simple multiplication. Did you obtain $$f(x,y)=\frac{\lambda }{\sqrt{2 \pi }} e^{-\lambda  x-\frac{1}{2} (x-y)^2}?$$ If not, then that's the calculation you should double-check. If so, then where is the obstacle to computing $f(x|y)$?

Comment: I dont know how to get f(y). I think it should be $\int f(x,y) dx$ then I stuck at the integration.